# Remote Debugging Scala Spark Jobs with VsCode

Tags: scala, apache-spark, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger, scala-metals

I'd like to have the ability to remote debug a Spark job written in Scala running in a docker container with VsCode. This is what I have so far,

1. VsCode with [scala-metals v0.8](https://scalameta.org/metals/blog/2020/01/10/cobalt.html) installed
2. This [debug launch configuration](https://github.com/aedenj/spark-job-starter/blob/vscode-debug-setup/.vscode/launch.json)
3. I spin up a spark cluster with [docker-compose up](https://github.com/aedenj/spark-job-starter/blob/vscode-debug-setup/docker-compose.yml)
4. I submit a spark job to the cluster started above with the following command

```
docker exec -it -e SPARK_SUBMIT_OPTS=-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=4000 -w /spark spark-job-starter_master_1 bin/spark-submit --class example.StarterSparkJob /build/example.jar
```

After doing so I see the output `Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 4000`

5. I attempt to launch the debugger from VsCode, but I get the error.

```
Debugger failed to attach: handshake failed - received >Content-Length< - expected >JDWP-Handshake<
```

The full details of the code are here https://github.com/aedenj/spark-job-starter/tree/vscode-debug-setup. Your guidance is appreciated.